# Is there a way to change the background of button when use cursor attribute on Chrome?

Tags: html, css, cursor

I'm working with CSS and facing some problems with using a cursor attribute CSS on the Chrome browser. I would like to change/remove the discover background which is shown in the below image. It's the first button.

[image]

This discover background won't appear if I don't use cursor attribute CSS (cursor: pointer).

Comment: Where is html/css?

Comment: you can try with these codes.
 
HTML: <button> abc </button>
CSS: button { 
 padding: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
}

I found that the problem came from Chrome browser. It didn't happen on Firefox